# Guide about twitter login in web without using any third party library

Tags: java, web, twitter, twitter-login

I find a way to implement twitter login with github twitter4j but I want to implement it without using any third party library. With the twitter document, I am not able to understand what should I do for it. From where I can get oauth_nonce, oauth_timestamp & oauth_signature's value? Please suggest me a good way to implement twitter login in web.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to implement it from scratch. Remember the old saying "Do not try to reinvent the wheel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am myself the developer of a ThirdParty library and I will definitely advise to use them. Twitter authentication has multiple problems to consider.

Anyway here is an answer for you.

```
// oauth_nonce
var oauth_nonce = new Random().Next(123400, 9999999).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// oauth_timestamp
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var oauthTimestamp = Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Signature is a bit more complicated. You need to extract all the params of your query. Order them by name, Append all of them into a string separated with '&' (lets call it URL_PARAMETERS).
Then create a string as followed `{HTTP_METHOD}&{BASE_URL}&{URL_PARAMETERS}`

Now you simply have to compute the Hash of the previous value with the oauth_secret_key (from Twitter app).

And not you can simply do  `oauth_signature = Http.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64(<HASH>))`.

Also don't forget

```
var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";
```

Answer (score 2):

> Please suggest me a good way to implement twitter login in web.

The [Twitter developer documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/introduction) says this:

> *"Most developers will not need to work with the details of OAuth, since Twitter Client Libraries already implement the protocol. **It is strongly recommended to use one of these libraries.** "*

If you choose to ignore that advice, then the same page has links to other pages that explain OAuth, explain various ways to get tokens, and explain how to ad authentication details to your requests.